# Choose elements of a list and delete others

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list and I want to choose randomly n elements, but each time that draw a element I need to delete the other elements whit some in common:

```
list= {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 
 4}, {6, 1}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 5}, {7, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 4}, {7, 
 5}, {7, 6}, {8, 1}, {8, 2}, {8, 3}, {8, 5}, {8, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 
 2}, {9, 3}, {9, 4}, {9, 6}, {9, 7}, {9, 8}, {10, 1}, {10, 3}, {10, 
 4}, {10, 5}, {10, 7}, {10, 8}, {10, 9}, {11, 1}, {11, 2}, {11, 
 4}, {11, 5}, {11, 6}, {11, 8}, {11, 9}, {11, 10}, {12, 1}, {12, 
 2}, {12, 3}, {12, 5}, {12, 6}, {12, 7}, {12, 9}, {12, 10}, {12, 
 11}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 
 5}, {4, 5}, {1, 6}, {3, 6}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}, {1, 7}, {2, 7}, {4, 
 7}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}, {1, 8}, {2, 8}, {3, 8}, {5, 8}, {6, 8}, {7, 
 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 9}, {4, 9}, {6, 9}, {7, 9}, {8, 9}, {1, 10}, {3, 
 10}, {4, 10}, {5, 10}, {7, 10}, {8, 10}, {9, 10}, {1, 11}, {2, 
 11}, {4, 11}, {5, 11}, {6, 11}, {8, 11}, {9, 11}, {10, 11}, {1, 
 12}, {2, 12}, {3, 12}, {5, 12}, {6, 12}, {7, 12}, {9, 12}, {10, 
 12}, {11, 12}, {5, 1}, {6, 2}, {7, 3}, {8, 4}, {9, 1}, {9, 5}, {10, 
 2}, {10, 6}, {11, 3}, {11, 7}, {12, 4}, {12, 8}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3,
 7}, {4, 8}, {1, 9}, {5, 9}, {2, 10}, {6, 10}, {3, 11}, {7, 11}, {4,
 12}, {8, 12}}
```

Then if I draw `{2,12}` I need to delete all elements that have 2 or/and 12 `{{12,2},{2, 1},{3,2},{4,2}....}`
I need to have into account the weights:

```
list2={0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.18, \
 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, \
 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, \
 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, \
 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.27, \
 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, \
 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, \
 0.18, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, \
 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, \
 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.37, 0.37, \
 0.28, 0.28, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.37, \
 0.37, 0.28, 0.28, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you look for:

```
step[{pairs_, weights_}] := Module[{choice, pos},
  choice = RandomChoice[weights -> pairs];
  pos = Position[pairs, 
    Alternatives @@ 
     Map[x \[Function] Sequence @@ {{x, _}, {_, x}}, choice], 1];
  {
   choice,
   {Delete[pairs, pos], Delete[weights, pos]}
   }
  ]
```

You may use it as follows:

```
{choice, {newlist, newlist2}} = step[{list, list2}]
```

Of course, you can use that repeatedly on order to choose `n` elements.

Comment: @H Schumacher . Congratulations it works nice and clean, Now need to study how you use Alternatives, \[Function]

Comment: `\[Function]` is the infix form of `Function`. `Alternatives` is for creating a pattern that matches your needs, so that `Position` can do the lookup.

Comment: Nice! @Henrik Schumacher. ...but...isn´t clear for me the `Sequence`. I went to Help but i don´t understand exactly  the:  `Sequence @@ {{x, _}, {_, x}}`..

Comment: `@@` is the infix form of `Apply` and `Sequence` is like `List` "but without braces". So, `Sequence @@ {{x, _}, {_, x}}` is a programmatic way to turn `{{x, _}, {_, x}}` into `{x, _}, {_, x}`. Note that `Map[x \[Function] {{x, _}, {_, x}}, {a,b}]` would return `{{{a,_},{_,a}}, {{b,_},{_,b}}}` but we want ``{{a,_},{_,a}, {b,_},{_,b}}`` here.